# How to take real time input output from a python script on PHP

Tags: php, python

I want to take input from user through a html form, process it through a python script and print the output on html page. The problem is the whole python script is executed each time, while I want the script to give real time output for each input. How can I manage to do this ?

Here is what I am doing so far.

```
<?php
    $vout='';
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $vin=$_POST['input_text'];
        $vout=exec('python bot.py '.$vin);
    }
?>
<form method="post">
<label>
    BotIn: <input type="text" name="input_text">
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</br></br>
<label>
    <p>Bot: <?=$vout?></p>
</label>
```

Comment: What do you mean by real time output?

Comment: @Ahmad basically I want the python script to keep running in background, as soon as the user submits input through html forms, I want the script to process it and print the output.

Comment: Such thing is not going to be easy. Maybe you can write a daemon using python and run it on the server, and request it via network and get the response. This is the typical way, but as I mentioned it is not so easy

Comment: By daemon, I mean a server program, that listens on the network

Comment: I am a beginner and I am unable to follow you on this, can't this be done using PHP popen() functions ?.

Comment: I have no idea about using `popen` for such thing

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your problem will be running simple python app using, let's say, [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) and hit to specific endpoint you'll make in it. Everything then could take place through localhost, if you'll set it on the same machine.